# C display font map pixels on screen

Tags: c, fonts, sdl

I'm currently learning about fontmaps and bitmaps,
I'd like to be able to take this fontmap, and output it to the screen in pixels.

```
unsigned char glyph_a[][8] = 
{
  {0x00, 0x00, 0x3c, 0x02, 0x3e, 0x42, 0x3e, 0x00},
}
```

The function I'm trying to use for this is

```
void draw_Glyph(char *glyph_a)
{
 int x, y;
 int set;
 for (x=0; x < 8; x++)
 {
  for (y=0; y < 8; y++)
  {
    set = glyph_a[x] & 1 << y;
  }
 }
}
```

SDL provides a function called SDL_RenderDrawPoint which takes the renderer, and an x and y value for location.

C has a graphics library for something called putpixel() where it also just takes the x and y values of the pixel, and also takes a color as the last argument.

I'm not sure what function I should be using to output this to pixels specifically. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The function `putpixel()` is part of the ancient `<graphics.h>` header and is not related to SDL in any way. You should use [`SDL_RenderDrawPoint()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderDrawPoint) if you want to draw a pixel on a [`SDL_Renderer`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Renderer). Moreover, if you want to change the color of the pixel that is being drawn, call [SDL_SetRenderDrawColor()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetRenderDrawColor) before calling `SDL_RenderDrawPoint()`.

Comment: @Ruks So what's the way to get the X, Y values for the SDL_RenderDrawPoint() function, should I make that set function a set_x and a set_y to get the kind of results I'm looking for? Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your `draw_Glyph()` function to this:

```
struct Color {
    Uint8 r, g, b, a;
}

Color create_Color(Uint8 r, Uint8 g, Uint8 b, Uint8 a) {
    Color clr;
    clr.r = r;
    clr.g = g;
    clr.b = b;
    clr.a = a;
    return clr;
}

void draw_Glyph(SDL_Renderer* renderer, /* Renderer instance to draw the glyph on */
                char* glyph,            /* The glyph to display */
                Color on_color,         /* Color to use for 'on' bits in the glyph */
                Color off_color         /* Color to use for 'off' bits in the glyph */
                )
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            // Check if the bit is 'on' or 'off' and set the color of the pixel accordingly
            if (glyph[y] & (1 << (7 - x)))
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, on_color.r, on_color.g, on_color.b, on_color.a);
            else
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, off_color.r, off_color.g, off_color.b, off_color.a);
            // Draw the point where it is needed
            SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x, y);
        }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
const Color on_clr = create_Color(255, 255, 255, 255); // WHITE
const Color off_clr = create_Color(0, 0, 0, 255);      // BLACK
draw_Glyph(renderer, *glyph_a, on_clr, off_clr);
```

Do note that you *need* to pass an `SDL_Renderer*` instance in order to use it.

You can find a minimal example on how to create an `SDL_Renderer` on [SDL's website](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRenderer).